# WEKA J48 setting the root manually

Tags: weka, j48

Is there any ways to force setting root of a decision tree in j48 using weka? Because I want to see clearly if the root is changed, what will be the changes caused to the tree.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with the current implementation.